# htaccess, If subdomain is not "dev" follow these instructions

Tags: .htaccess, addhandler

**How can I do it right?**
If subdomain is not "dev" follow these instructions

```php
RewriteEngine On
Options +MultiViews
Options +FollowSymlinks

# -----------------%<-----------------
# If subdomain is not "dev"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.*
# follow these instructions
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
MultiviewsMatch Handlers Filters
# -----------------%<-----------------
```

Comment: By checking the content of the _correct_ environment variable - `%{HTTPS}` is obviously not it. You want to check `%{HTTP_HOST}`

Comment: I have prescribed myself. now it's on HTTP_HOST

Answer (score 1):

That is nothing you should configure in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), that is not what those files are for. Instead this should be implemented in a separate virtual host where you don't need a condition at all.

A `RewriteCond` is part of the rewriting module, you cannot somehow use it in combination with directives of other modules.

You can try something like that, but as said I would advise against that:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'dev.example.com'">
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    MultiviewsMatch Handlers Filters
</If>
```

This is where you can find the documentation: 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples